# Spark command for alphabets

Tags: apache-spark

I have a data frame with columns as customer_id, postal_code, gender, age..I want to display the data only where postal_code is with alphabets. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html) , if you are fimilar with SQL, its similar to LIKE clause

For you use case you can use Rlike - Alphabets Only

#### Data Preparation

```
input_str = """
Alicja       London        44
Alicja       Germany       Berlin
Alicja       India         91
Piotr        Arizona       USA
ABC          India         P4G32L
""".split()

input_values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, input_str))

cols = list(map(lambda x: x.strip() if x.strip() != 'null' else None, "name,country,postal_code".split(',')))
        
n = len(input_values)
n_cols = 3

input_list = [tuple(input_values[i:i+n_cols]) for i in range(0,n,n_cols)]

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(input_list, cols)

sparkDF.show()

+------+-------+-----------+
|  name|country|postal_code|
+------+-------+-----------+
|Alicja| London|         44|
|Alicja|Germany|     Berlin|
|Alicja|  India|         91|
| Piotr|Arizona|        Usa|
|   ABC|  India|     P4G32L|
+------+-------+-----------+
```

#### RLike - AlphaNumeric (Alpha or Numeric)

```
sparkDF.filter(F.col("postal_code").rlike("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")).show()

+------+-------+-----------+
|  name|country|postal_code|
+------+-------+-----------+
|Alicja| London|         44|
|Alicja|Germany|     Berlin|
|Alicja|  India|         91|
| Piotr|Arizona|        Usa|
|   ABC|  India|     P4G32L|
+------+-------+-----------+
```

#### RLike - Alphabets

```
sparkDF.filter(F.col("postal_code").rlike("^[A-Z][a-zA-Z].+")).show()

+------+-------+-----------+
|  name|country|postal_code|
+------+-------+-----------+
|Alicja|Germany|     Berlin|
| Piotr|Arizona|        Usa|
+------+-------+-----------+
```

#### RLike - Numeric

```
sparkDF.filter(F.col("postal_code").rlike("^[0-9]*$")).show()

+------+-------+-----------+
|  name|country|postal_code|
+------+-------+-----------+
|Alicja| London|         44|
|Alicja|  India|         91|
+------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Will this work if the postal_code is P4G32L….both alphabets and numeric in the same

Comment: You ll have to modify the regex search , if you want to filter on alphanumeric values  you can easily do that

Comment: May I know the command for that please?